# Can I configure Apache httpd to remove/replace all request headers that match a pattern?

Tags: apache-2.4, httpd, http-headers

I'm using Apache httpd as a reverse proxy in front of a web application. Authentication is carried out by a module (mod_auth_mellon), which sets various request environment variables with details about the authenticated user (user name, display name and so on).

I use mod_headers to remove headers from the incoming request, and replace them with the value of request environment variables that were set by mod_auth_mellon.

```
RequestHeader unset mellon_uid
RequestHeader set mellon_uid "%{mellon_uid}e" env=mellon_uid
```

Thus any client-provided `mellon_uid` header is thrown away. If mod_auth_mellon considers the user to be logged in then a new `mellon_uid` request header is added to the request that is sent onward to the web application.

So far I've made this manageable by using mod_macro:

```
Use Attribute uid
Use Attribute display_name
Use Attribute email
```

... and so on, where `Attribute` is a macro that expands to the two `RequestHeader` directives above for the provided attribute.

However, some user details are multi-valued, for which mod_auth_mellon sets multiple request environment variables of the form:

```
mellon_foo_0 = first
mellon_foo_1 = second
mellon_foo_2 = third
mellon_foo_N = 3
```

Since the number of values for an attribute can vary, I can't rely on a static list of variables to process like this.

I would like to avoid using `MellonMergeEnvVars`, which would instead set the following:

```
mellon_foo = first;second;third
mellon_foo_N = 3
```

... because this means the web application now has to deal with the complexity of correctly parsing the `mellon_foo` request header, dealing with values that themselves contain semicolons, etc. Indeed, it's not clear to me that mod_auth_mellon performs any escaping, which makes unambiguous parsing impossible (if I'm right...)

Answer (score 0):

I think that as long as you only look at the first `mellon_foo_N` values, there shouldn't be any risk here, because mod_auth_mellon will always set those values itself, overriding any values the user might try to send. It should also always set `mellon_foo_N`, but you could always unset it initially to be sure.